# How to read the message of a specific size from `GzipInputStream` in protobuf in C++?

Tags: c++, gzip, protocol-buffers

I want to read the message of a specific size from a network socket. The size is encoded before the message it-self. The size + message are gzipped with `GzipOutputStream`.

Here goes the simplified sample code of my decoder:

```
unsigned size;
GzipInputStream gzip_stream(&file_input_stream_, GzipInputStream::ZLIB);
{
  CodedInputStream coded_stream(&gzip_stream);
  coded_stream.ReadVarint32(&size);
}

message->ParseFromBoundedZeroCopyStream(&gzip_stream, size);
```

In the documentation on `MessageLite::ParseFromBoundedZeroCopyStream()` there are contrary statements:

- Read a protocol buffer from the given zero-copy input stream, *expecting the message to be exactly "size" bytes long*.
- If successful, *exactly this many bytes will have been consumed from the input*.

So, I'm confused - will this function read `size` bytes from the stream, or will it expect the message of `size` bytes? - I suggest the former, since I can't properly read two messages consequently from the same socket.

---

### Question:

How to properly read the message of a specific size (`SerializeAsString().size()`) from `GzipInputStream`?

Answer (score 1):

The bullet points are not contradictory. Since `ParseFromBoundedZeroCopyStream` doesn't know what kind of stream it's reading from, the documentation is of course referring to the size of the data that it gets out of the stream, post-decompression. It will read exactly `size` *uncompressed* bytes from the stream, interpreting them as a single message. If you only know the compressed size of your message then you cannot use this method; you'll have to do something more complicated, e.g. layer the `GzipInputStream` on top of a `LimitingInputStream`.

(Note also that if the method returns false to indicate failure, then it may have stopped reading early, leaving your stream in an indeterminate state. If this is a problem, you'll have to do something more complicated to make sure you read the full size even in case of parse error, such as setting up a `LimitingInputStream` yourself and explicitly draining it of data after a parse failure.)